# Bootstrap 3 Complex Column Layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to work out if this layout is even possible in bootstrap 3.

bootstrap 3 grid layout:

[image]

There's a couple issues I can't see if there's a way around, mainly the items in red boxes need to collapse together on smaller screens. And I can't set those as col-10/col-2 since the col-10 has the 5 column row.

Is this impossible or is there some kind of work around I'm not seeing?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: what do you mean by 'collapsing together' ?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question by editing it.  Also, you can read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question.  Better questions tend to get quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: @ochi the last red box would need to come after everything in the first red box. ie I wouldn't be able to do row col-sm-10, col-sm-2 & row col-sm-2 x5 since it wouldn't display properly on mobile. The thinner row is a header for whats below. I ended up getting permission to scrap the last column so got around this issue that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using vanilla Bootstrap 3 classes, because the 12-unit grid system is not evenly divisible by 5 columns. At best, you can offset the first column with `.col-md-offset-1`, which adds half-column spaces around the five columns.

I recommend trying out the [Bootstrap 4 grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)! It is based on flexbox and can handle 5 columns.

Comment: This is what I figured, we're going to be re-doing the website soon so not worth the effort to upgrade this version. I ended up getting permission to scrap the content in the last column so that was easier.

Comment: @jessicap324 would you help me out by clicking the checkmark to [accept this answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: woops yup sorry!